# how to obtain the consent of the DPP for a private prosecution in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, consent, prosecution

For a person in the UK considering taking forward a private prosecution, according to this [form](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-for-summons-or-warrant-for-arrest-for-an-alleged-offence):

"Application for summons or warrant for arrest for alleged offence under Magistrates’ Courts Act 1980 section 1, CrimPR 7.2(6)".

The first comment in this form is about "consent to prosecute", in detail

**(1)  Consent to prosecute
Do you need consent to prosecute?                            Yes     No
If yes, you must include with your application written evidence of that consent.
Some offences may not be prosecuted without the consent of the Attorney General, the Director of Public Prosecutions or another authority. The legislation that creates the offence will say whether such consent is required.**

If the case involves conspiracy to pervert the course of justice but there are also time-limited aspects, how does one actually go to get the consent from either the Attorney General or the Director of Public Prosecutions and does it matter whether it is one body or the other?

Comment: This may be best answered by either a FOI request, or a less formal inquiry directly to the CPS.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/consent-of-the-attorney-general-to-prosecute-how-to-apply